# Passing command-line arguments in C#

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to pass command-line arguments to a C# application, but I have problem passing something like this

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\App name"
```

even if I add `" "` to the argument.

Here is my code:

```
    public ObjectModel(String[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 0) return; //no command line arg.
        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(args.Length.ToString());
        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(args[0]);
        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(args[1]);
        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(args[2]);
        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(args[3]);
        if (args.Length == 3)
        {
            try
            {
                RemoveInstalledFolder(args[0]);
                RemoveUserAccount(args[1]);
                RemoveShortCutFolder(args[2]);
                RemoveRegistryEntry();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
        }
```

And here is what I'm passing:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Uninstaller.exe  "C:\Program Files\Application name\"  "username"  "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\application name"
```

The problem is I can get the first and the second args correctly, but the last one it gets as `C:\Documents`.

Any help?

Comment: What are you trying to start this from? Command line or another program? If the latter - what is the language?

Comment: What happens when you pass an argument like this into your application?

Comment: Can you past your code that tries to access the argument and also the full command line you are typing, such as c:\myapp.exe "c:\documents\appname"

Comment: Looks okay, what exactly goes wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I just ran a check and verified the problem. It surprised me, but it is the last \ in the first argument.

```
"C:\Program Files\Application name\" <== remove the last '\'
```

This needs more explanation, does anybody have an idea? I'm inclined to call it a bug.

---

Part 2, I ran a few more tests and

```
"X:\\aa aa\\" "X:\\aa aa\" next
```

becomes

```
X:\\aa aa\
X:\\aa aa" next
```

A little Google action gives some insight from a [blog by Jon Galloway](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/10/05/_5B002E00_NET-Gotcha_5D00_-Commandline-args-ending-in-_5C002200_-are-subject-to-CommandLineToArgvW-whackiness.aspx), the basic rules are:

- the backslash is the escape character
- always escape quotes
- only escape backslashes when they precede a quote.

Comment: It's fixed by removing \ from the first arg. Thanks alot

Comment: If you want that trailing backslash, you can add another one.  That is, "abd\\" on the command line results in an argument of "abd\".

Comment: @Henk: Sorry.  Forest/trees here. I need a vacation.

Comment: Here is a GitHub project with Encode/Decode methods that handle issues mentioned by Jon Galloway: https://github.com/ericpopivker/Command-Line-Encoder

Comment: link to [Raymond Chen's post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100917-00/?p=12833) mentioned in [Jon Galloway's post](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/_5B002E00_NET-Gotcha_5D00_-Commandline-args-ending-in-_5C002200_-are-subject-to-CommandLineToArgvW-whackiness)

Answer (score 5):

To add Ian Kemp's answer

If you assembly is called "myProg.exe" and you pass in the string "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\App name" link so

```
C:\>myprog.exe "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\App name"
```

the string "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\App name"

will be at args[0].

Comment: However: the case at hand is that if you call `myprog.exe "c:\one\" "two" "three"`, then args[0] will be `c:\one" two three`. try it out!

Answer (score 1):

To add to what everyone else has already said, It might be an escaping problem. You should escape your backslashes by another backslash.

Should be something like:

C:\>myprog.exe "C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Start Menu\\Programs\\App name"

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same annoying issue recently, and decided to write a parser to parse the command line arguments array out myself.

Note: the issue is that the .NET CommandLine Arguments passed to the static void Main(string[] args) function escapes \" and \\.  This is by design, since you may actually want to pass an argument that has a quote or backslash in it.  One example:

say you wanted to pass the following as a single argument:

> -msg:Hey, "Where you at?"

eg.

> sampleapp -msg:"Hey, \"Where you
>   at?\""

Would be how to send it with the default behavior.

If you don't see a reason for anyone to have to escape quotes or backslashes for your program, you could utilize your own parser to parse the command line, as below.

IE.
[program].exe "C:\test\" arg1 arg2

would have a args[0] = c:\test" arg1 arg2

What you would expect is args[0]=c:\test\ and then args[1]=arg1 and args[2]=arg2.

The below function parses the arguments into a list with this simplified behavior.

Note, arg[0] is the program name using the below code.  (You call List.ToArray() to convert the resulting list to a string array.)

```
protected enum enumParseState : int { StartToken, InQuote, InToken };
public static List<String> ManuallyParseCommandLine()
{
    String CommandLineArgs = Environment.CommandLine.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("Command entered: " + CommandLineArgs);

    List<String> listArgs = new List<String>();

    Regex rWhiteSpace = new Regex("[\\s]");
    StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();
    enumParseState eps = enumParseState.StartToken;

    for (int i = 0; i < CommandLineArgs.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = CommandLineArgs[i];
    //    Console.WriteLine(c.ToString()  + ", " + eps);
        //Looking for beginning of next token
        if (eps == enumParseState.StartToken)
        {
            if (rWhiteSpace.IsMatch(c.ToString()))
            {
                //Skip whitespace
            }
            else
            {
                token.Append(c);
                eps = enumParseState.InToken;
            }


        }
        else if (eps == enumParseState.InToken)
        {
            if (rWhiteSpace.IsMatch(c.ToString()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Token: [" + token.ToString() + "]");
                listArgs.Add(token.ToString().Trim());
                eps = enumParseState.StartToken;

                //Start new token.
                token.Remove(0, token.Length);
            }
            else if (c == '"')
            {
               // token.Append(c);
                eps = enumParseState.InQuote;
            }
            else
            {
                token.Append(c);
                eps = enumParseState.InToken;
            }

        }
            //When in a quote, white space is included in the token
        else if (eps == enumParseState.InQuote)
        {
            if (c == '"')
            {
               // token.Append(c);
                eps = enumParseState.InToken;
            }
            else
            {
                token.Append(c);
                eps = enumParseState.InQuote;
            }

        }


    }
    if (token.ToString() != "")
    {
        listArgs.Add(token.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Final Token: " + token.ToString());
    }
    return listArgs;
}
```

Comment: this seems to break if the first character is a quote

Answer (score 1):

In response to WWC's answer, Jamezor commented that his code will fail if the first character is a quote.

To fix that problem, you can replace the StartToken case with this:

```
            if (eps == enumParseState.StartToken)
            {
                if (rWhiteSpace.IsMatch(c.ToString()))
                {
                    //Skip whitespace
                }
                else if (c == '"')
                {
                    eps = enumParseState.InQuote;
                }
                else
                {
                    token.Append(c);
                    eps = enumParseState.InToken;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem? Anyway here's some general advice:

Make sure your Main method (in Program.cs) is defined as:

```
void Main(string[] args)
```

Then args is an array containing the command-line arguments.