# how to parse main arguments?

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

How can I find this information :

think we started this process :

```
testFile.exe i- 100 k- "hello" j-"C:\" "D:\Images" f- "true"
```

Now how can I get main argument when application started so I have :

```
int i = ... ; //i will be 100
string k = ... ; // k = hello
string[] path = ... ; // = path[0] = "C:\" , path[1] = "D:\Images"
bool f = ... ; // f = true;
```

regards

Comment: While this is not what you're asking about, you should be aware that this command-line syntax doesn't adhere to any of the usual conventions (e.g. `-x ...` on UNIX-like systems, or `/x ...` on Windows systems) and people will probably have a hard time remembering it.

Comment: Consider writing `-i 100 -k "hello"` etc, instead of `i- 100 k- "hello"` - almost all programs out there use the `-i` style and for good reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments are passed to the `Main` function that is being called:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    // The args array contain all the arguments being passed:
    // args[0] = "i-"
    // args[1] = "100"
    // args[2] = "k-"
    // args[3] = "hello"
    // ...
}
```

Arguments are in the same order as passed in the command line. If you want to use named arguments you may take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c) which suggests [NDesk.Options](http://www.ndesk.org/Options) and [Mono.Options](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/branches/mono-2-2/mcs/class/Mono.Options/).

Comment: Right, except that the array is zero based, not one based.

Comment: Yeah - some environments pass the exe name in the 0th argument, but fortunately this stupid convention is gone from .NET.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Environment.CommandLine** or **Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()**

```
String[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

As already answered, you can use the `string[] args` parameter or  `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`. Note that for CLickOnce deployed apps you need something else.

You can do your own processing on the `string[]` or use a library, like [this one](http://commandline.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.

For some tricky details on spaces in filenames and escaping quotes, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653563/passing-command-line-arguments-in-c/653664#653664).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [NDesk.Options](http://www.ndesk.org/Options). Here is their [documentation](http://www.ndesk.org/doc/ndesk-options/).