# Passing a C# string to VBscript

Tags: c#, .net, vbscript

I am using a windows form and am trying to pass a string to a vbscript. The program is asking the user to select a folder, I am trying to take the folder selection and pass it through to the vbscript.

C# Code:

```
String SelectedFolder = @"C:\Users";

        folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = SelectedFolder;
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            //Set selectedFolder equal to the folder that was choosen
            SelectedFolder = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    //Call VBScript
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(".vbsPath");
```

VBScript:

```
TargetFolder = Request.QueryString("SelectedFolder")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(TargetFolder)
Set colItems = objFolder.Items
For Each objItem in colItems
objItem.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
Next
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Request.QueryString? so you want to pass the string to a classic-asp page written in vbscript as a url argument?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am very new to vbscript and have been looking for a way to access the string; the Request.QueryString was the only thing that I have found that looked like it might work but does not. Is there any way to pass the C# string to VBscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C# side**

Use the [Process.Start overload that accepts command-line parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\path\to\my.vbs", selectedFolder);
```

If the selectedFolder can contain spaces (which is likely to happen), you should enclose the argument in quotes.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\path\to\my.vbs", 
    "\"" + selectedFolder + "\"");
```

In fact, if the path can contain quotes and/or trailing backslashes, escaping gets a lot more complicated, see these questions (and others) for details: [Escape command line arguments in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5510343/87698), [Passing command-line arguments in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/653563/87698).

---

**VBScript side**

In your VBScript, read the first command line parameter:

```
targetFolder = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
```

Comment: Trying it out now. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @dhk: You're welcome! Don't forget to click on the check mark next to my answer, so that others know that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the string to a file which both sets of code can access, or a database. That way it won't matter which programming language you are using at all e.g. could be C# to PHP.

Write file:

```
string content = "folder=" + folder;
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\config.txt");
file.WriteLine(content);
file.Close();
```

Read file:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\config.txt");
string content = file.ReadToEnd();
// extract value of folder setting here
file.Close();
```

(Of course the reading would need to be in VB, but would be very similar. Note: code based on: [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287548.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Going back and forth from VBScript to C# is adding a lot of complexity.  If possible, it would really be easier to choose one or the other.

You can do anything in C# that you can in VBScript.  (How you do it is probably different, but you can do all the same tasks - file access, database access, etc.)  If it's feasible, you may be better off just working in C#.

I'm doing a bit of a guess based on the context of the question here, but I'm trying to answer in my own head why you'd want to do this, and the only thing I can think of is that you don't know how to display a folder dialog box in VBScript, so you're resorting to trying to do it in C#.  Is that correct?

If so, you can show a folder dialog in VBScript as shown here: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_browsefolder.php

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am trying to cycle through each file in a folder and print them, I know it can be done in VB.net but I cannot find the equivalent in C#.net. Looking back at it now, I should have phrased this question differently(Sorry I'm quite new to the site).