# Passing filepath into Main(string[] args) not working

Tags: c#, console-application, program-entry-point, filepath, args

I am trying to pass a file path into a `C# Console Application` but am having problems with the string being incorrect by the time it reaches the console application.

If I run my application from the command line, with a file path parameter:

```
MyApp "C:\Users\DevDave\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyProject\"
```

A windows dialogue pops up and informs me that my application has stopped working, and when I click the Debug option, I can see that the result of `args[0]` is:

C:\Users\DevDave\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyProject"

Note there is still a trailing quote at the end.

If I pass a second argument:

```
MyApp "C:\Users\DevDave\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyProject\" "any old string"
```

I get an error again, and after viewing in debug I see that args[0] is:

C:\Users\DevDave\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyProject" any

I am baffled as to why this is happening. My only guess is that the backslashes in the string are causing some kind of escape sequence from the string? **Edit**: I notice that the same is happening in the string example above! It seems \" is causing problems here.

I just want to pass in the file path of the current solution directory and am calling my app from a pre-build event using $(SolutionDir), and know that I can get the path of the current solution in other ways. But this is simplest and I am curious as to why it does not work as expected.

Comment: I know that is not straight answer, but you can get current path from `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

Comment: @PhilipGullick @ strings won't work in console.

Comment: #Deletes comment and hides. I don't know what I was reading...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the rules for commandline arguments are a little murky.

The `\` is the escape char and you can use it to escape quotes (`"`). You'll have to escape a  backslash but only when it is preceding a quote. So use (note the '\\' at the end):

```
MyApp "C:\Users\DevDave\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyProject\\"
```

or, simpler but you'll have to deal with it in C# somehow:

```
MyApp "C:\Users\DevDave\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyProject"
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/653563/60761)

Comment: Can you try 
    MyApp "C:\Users\DevDave\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyProject\

Comment: @NisargShah - not sure what you mean, probably your formatting got mixed up. The `\\` is special in comments too.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I sorta hate you, because every time (ok not every time, but quite often) when I'm about to post an answer you're beating me to it :) I really need more stackoverflow practice.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov - you can search Meta for "fastest gun", you're not the only one with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

That's why it's always better to use `/` in path

```
"C:/Users/DevDave/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/MyProject/" "any old string"
```

take a look: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing) , you can use both `\` and `/` in path but if you want any shell compatibility I suggest to use `/`

Answer (score 1):

Anything that comes after MyApp will be the first argument (args[0]). In your case, the first argument is `"C:\Users\DevDave\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyProject\"`. Also, the quote at the end of the string seems to happen because `\"` means that you want to want to escape the quote and write it as a string. In this case, the quote is not closing the string. That is the reason that your args[0] is the whole thing that comes after `MyApp`

If you don't want to scape the quote and have a slash behind it, you should do `\\"`

You could try this and tell me what happens:

```
MyApp "C:\Users\DevDave\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyProject\\"
```

(look at the double slash)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Continuation of Henk's answer, and choose to add a `\` at the end of the path, then:

If you choose to hack the bug by choosing this code in Henk's answer ("simpler but you'll have to deal with it in C# somehow:"), then you should realize some bugs that will occur:

1. args[0] will only be set, even if you pass multiple parameters in.  The length of args will be equal to 1.  So you have to split args[0] into multiple pieces for your hack.
2. You have to replace any `"` characters with a `\` if they are at the end of the pieces you split.